# How to configure gwt location in Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I have a college project based on java swing. I wanted to use windowbuilder as a gui designer. When I start a new project, I am prompted to configure the GWT location. I tried a lot to configure the location but was not succesful.
I am using Eclipse 'Helios' in ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the Google Web Toolkit sdk and unzip/untar it. In the `Preferences > Google > Web toolkit` section, Add the sdk by pointing to the location where you unzipped the sdk.

However, I dont understand why do you need to (and how would you ) use GWT for Swing Application. Enlighten me.

Comment: WindowBuilder supports Swing as well as SWT.

Comment: Actually my college project is about "Online Examination System".Since it would be a browser based application, I just wanted to try out GWT.Basically I wanted to try out the GUI designer.

Anyways...thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: @Vikash, You are welcome :) In that case, its not a swing project. swing projects are typically dekstop application (not considering the obsolete applets here)